# Necessary conditions for AlertDialog to open

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Many of us have come across the dreaded

> E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked

This can happen for several reasons as is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added) and in many other SO questions.

I have tried making sure my dialogs are in a "good place" before showing them, often wrapping them around certain conditions like:

```
if (!isFinishing() && !isDestroyed()) {
    mDialog.show();
}
```

I'm curious if anyone knows of a "perfect environment" for which an AlertDialog is guaranteed to always display without error. From personal experience, even with the above conditions, the WindowLeaked error still always comes up.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a problem I faced when changing the orientation of the Activity, whenever we try to display a dialog with a closed Activity this error will skyrocket. In a less important case, as in a Activity data recording information, I simply ignore the Dialog and closing with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  
    try  {  
            if  (myAlertDialog != null && myAlertDialog.isShowing())  {  
                myAlertDialog.dismiss();  
                myAlertDialog = null ;  
            }  
        }  catch  (Exception  e)  { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
}
```

But if you need to keep it on the screen, the only way I found was locking the orientation of Activity.